# The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ''. Java -> Access -> Sharepoint List

Tags: java, ms-access, sharepoint-2010, database-connection

I am trying to connect to SharePoint List via Access Database. My Java code accesses the Access DB which is linked to a SharePoint List. It worked fine but now I am getting this Error:

SEVERE: ERROR!![Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'SPOT'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'SPOT' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'SPOT'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'SPOT' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

My Database Name: SPOT
Table Name: SPOT

Connection String:

```
connURL = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + accessFilePath;
```

Access 2013 64 bit
JDK 7 64 bit
Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 64 bit 
Windows Server 2008 64 bit
SharePoint 2010

The same code works on a different machine with configuration:
Access 2010 32 bit
JDK 7 32 bit
Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 32 bit 
Windows 7 64 bit
SharePoint 2010

Also the same code works if its not a linked List but a simple table. But I want it to be a linked list.

The DB name, Table name are right and are local. No error is there in the SharePoint List. I have checked with different SharePoint Lists.